# Hbase Sorted Map is physical view or just logical view?

Tags: hbase

As I know that Hbase is sorted map.
Is that meant the data is kept in HDD in sorted order according to its key?
Or sorted map is just logical view?

If it's physical view, that meant Hbase is fast to read and write to storage because it can reduce HDD arm swing for good queries.

But I don't sure it's really sorted in physical storage.

Anyone confirm?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everything in HBase is keep sorted.  The memstore is sorted.  Each HFile has all of the KeyValue's in that file sorted on disk.